# Angular with TypeScript: Unexpected behavior in contenteditable <td> element in HTML <table> with (blur) upon first text entry

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I encountered an unexpected behavior with contenteditable `<td>` element inside HTML `<table>` under Angular with TypeScript.

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Click on any of the two table cells
2. Enter some text (e.g. "abc")
3. Click on the other table cell

Expected: the text in the cell is "**abc**"

Observed: the text in the cell is "**abcabc**" (the text is doubled, two text nodes are added to DOM instead of one updated)

**Note:** the above is observed only if the cells are empty, i.e. `null` or `""`(empty string) as initial value. If one deletes the contents and adds text again - all works as expected (no doubling, see what you type)

**Can someone explain this behavior and suggest solution** (without changing `<td>` to `<input>`, i.e. preserving the `<table>` approach). Thank you.

Here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-table-td-issue)

**app.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'name', $event)">{{data?.name}}</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'age', $event)">{{data?.age}}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

Data: name[{{data?.name}}], age[{{data?.age}}]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public data = { name: null, age: null};

  public update(data, prop, ev) {
    data[prop] = ev.target.textContent;    // <-- !!!
  }
}
```

Comment: its working as intended the problem is that it isn't doubling the character you are typing it's just keeping whatever text you are typing in the td and then appending the typed text after blur

Comment: @khan Then why when you delete the cell content and start over the effect doesn't repeat ?

Comment: sorry didn't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: In the example above, data object initially has two props with 'null' value. In real-world scenario, I have OnInit that calls back-end to fetch info, which in turn is assigned to the data object. The result is that some <td>s are filled in (with strings) and others stay blank (null). The filled in don't display the observed effect, while the blank ones do. If I follow your suggestion, I will fix the problem, but won't have the possibility to assign what I have retrieved from the back-end to the data object. Does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" [textContent]="data?.name" (input)="data['name']=$event.target.textContent"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" [textContent]="data?.age" (input)="data['age']=$event.target.textContent"></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

use textContent input and input output on the td.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-table-td-issue-og3ore?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Brilliant ! This works and allows for two way data flow

Answer (score 1):

in your html edit these lines

```
<tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'name', $event)"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'age', $event)"></td> 
</tr>
```

component.ts

```
    text: any;
    public update(data, prop, ev) 
    {
        this.text = ev.target.textContent;
        ev.target.textContent = '';
        ev.target.textContent = this.text;
        data[prop] = this.text;
    }
```

Comment: your suggestion resolves the doubling of data (in this simplified example), but I need the {{}} binding (or similar) as in some of the <td>s I have data incoming. Can you alter your suggestion if you believe there's a way to evade the "effect" but still provide for incoming data (i.e. onInit some data fetched from BE and assigned to the data object) ?

Comment: i have edited my answer try that, i know the answer is looking wierd but its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'name', $event)" value="data?.name"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" (blur)="update(data, 'age', $event)" value="data?.name"></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

setting the value property will fix the problem.